# Google Account without Gmail -> possible to obtain Gmail later?

Tags: gmail, google-account

If I create Google Account without Gmail today, will I be able to change my mind and acquire Gmail address in the future, keeping the same Google Account? (The last part is important because other people might share content with a Google account I give them so I don't really want to be changing Google accounts altogether.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will be able to do so.

From https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/72198?hl=en

> ## Adding Gmail
>
> If you add Gmail to your Google Account, your account's primary
> username will permanently change to yourusername@gmail.com.
>
> After you add Gmail, the original email address associated with your
> account will become your [alternate email
> address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347). If you
> have verified your original email address before adding Gmail, you
> will be able to sign in using this email address.
>
> ### Adding Gmail to an existing Google Account
>
> 1. Go to [mail.google.com](http://mail.google.com).
> 2. Click **Sign up for Gmail**.
> 3. At the top of the page, click **If you already have a Google Account, you can sign in here**. You'll be redirected to a sign-in page.
> 4. Use your existing Google Account username and password to sign in. On the next page, you'll see a shortened Gmail sign-up form where you
>    can choose your Gmail username

Comment: Perfect. I was curious if I will be able to use my previous, non-gmail email as an account login as well, and I will so that's perfect.